# Loop through each record of a table and preform calculations on all other records

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate a value for `NO_TOP_RATING` in my table `working`

The calculation for `NO_TOP_RATING` is made by:

- For each row, get all other rows that fall within the previous year from `ANNDATS_CONVERTED` for that record, and have the same `ESTIMID` as that record.
- From those, find the lowest `IRECCD` value.
- Then, count the number of times that the same `ANALYST` has an `IRECCD` that matches the lowest `IRECCD` calculated.

**NOTE:** This should omit the current row being calculated (so to find the value for row id 1, do not use this row in the calculations) and any records where `ANALYST` is blank should be ignored altogether.

TABLE `working`:

```
    | ID | ANALYST |   ESTIMID    | ANNDATS_CONVERTED |   IRECCD    | NO_TOP_RATING |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 1  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-01     |     2       |               |
    | 2  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |     2       |               |
    | 3  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-02     |     4       |               |
    | 4  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-04     |     3       |               |
    | 5  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-14     |     1       |               |
    | 6  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |     4       |               |
    | 7  |         | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |     1       |               |
    | 8  |  DAVE   | Brokerage111 |    1998-06-28     |     5       |               |
```

---

So - when calculating `NO_TOP_RATING` for **record #1**:

- **record #1** would **not** be included in the calculation, because I want to omit it from the calculation
- **record #7** would **not** be included in the calculation at all, because `ANALYST` is blank
- **Record #8** would **not** be included in the calculation, because `ESTIMID` is not the same as record #1

---

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

TABLE `working`:

```
| ID | ANALYST |   ESTIMID    | ANNDATS_CONVERTED |   IRECCD    | NO_TOP_RATING |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-01     |     2       |       0       |
| 2  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |     2       |       0       |
| 3  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-02     |     4       |       0       |
| 4  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |    1998-07-04     |     3       |       0       |
| 5  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-14     |     1       |       0       |
| 6  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |     4       |       1       |
| 7  |         | Brokerage000 |    1998-06-28     |     1       |               |
| 8  |  DAVE   | Brokerage111 |    1998-06-28     |     5       |       0       |
```

---

Here is the MySQL I have so far:

```
    UPDATE `working`

SET `working`.`NO_TOP_RATING` = 


(
    SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM  (SELECT `ID`,`IRECCD`,`ESTIMID` FROM `working`) AS BB 

    WHERE

    `IRECCD` =                                  


            (
                SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM  (SELECT `ID`,`IRECCD`,`ESTIMID`, `ANALYST` FROM `working`) AS ZZ 
                WHERE

                `IRECCD` =
                            -- this calculates the LOWEST number with same `ESTIMID`
                            (

                                SELECT MIN(`IRECCD`)
                                FROM (SELECT `ID`,`IRECCD`,`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`,`ESTIMID` FROM `working`) AS CC 

                                WHERE
                                `ANNDATS_CONVERTED` >= DATE_SUB(`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
                                AND
                                `working`.`ESTIMID` = BB.`ESTIMID`

                            )
                            -- END this calculates the LOWEST number with same `ESTIMID`

                AND
                `working`.`ANALYST` = ZZ.`ANALYST`
            )




)
WHERE `working`.`ANALYST` != ''
```

---

This is working in PHP, looping through each record and evaluating all the other records for each. This involves looping and takes a very long time on a large database. I am trying to achieve the same result with MySQL.

Comment: Can you edit your questions to include your expected results for the sample data your shared?

Comment: There's still some confusion. For example, do you want rows that fall within a year *after* the date or *before* the date? So when calculating the value for row #1, should row #2 be included because it happened prior to row #1?

Comment: Thanks @McAdam331. The qualifying years are to be >= -1 year past  `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`. So one year ago, and up to the `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`. Yes - row #2 would be included, as it falls within the equal to or greater than 1 year ago.

Comment: Yes @McAdam331 I will edit the question to show the expected results. Thank you for your help. Regards.

Comment: thank you. I have an idea for a query but I would like to make sure the answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I took a few steps to solve this. The first thing I did was write a `JOIN` that got all of the rows I needed. I joined the table to itself on several conditions:

- The estimid matched
- The id value was not the same
- The analyst column was not null in either table
- The anndats_converted of one table was within the previous year of the other table.

To test, I selected the id from both tables to make sure I was getting proper pairings:

```
SELECT w.id, wo.id
FROM working w
JOIN working wo 
    ON w.estimid = wo.estimid
    AND w.id != wo.id
    AND w.analyst IS NOT NULL
    AND wo.analyst IS NOT NULL
    AND wo.anndats_converted BETWEEN DATE_SUB(w.anndats_converted, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND w.anndats_converted
ORDER BY w.id;
```

A brief result set showed the following pairings:

```
| id | id |
+----+----+
| 1  | 2  |
| 1  | 5  |
| 1  | 6  |
| 2  | 5  |
| 2  | 6  |
```

This seems to match what you wanted. For id #1, row 1 is excluded (because it is being calculated) rows 3 and 4 do not fall in the proper date range, row 7 is null and row 8 is a different estimid.

Then, I used an aggregate function to calculate the minimum ireccd by grouping by the first table:

```
SELECT w.id, w.analyst, MIN(wo.ireccd) AS min_ireccd
FROM working w
JOIN working wo 
    ON w.estimid = wo.estimid
    AND w.id != wo.id
    AND w.analyst IS NOT NULL
    AND wo.analyst IS NOT NULL
    AND wo.anndats_converted BETWEEN DATE_SUB(w.anndats_converted, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND w.anndats_converted
GROUP BY w.id;
```

The next part was also tricky so I'll explain it in two steps. I joined the above query with the original table, with the only condition that the analyst column matched. What this did was create a Cartesian Product, in a way. The query looked like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM working w
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT w.id, w.analyst, MIN(wo.ireccd) AS min_ireccd
    FROM working w
    LEFT JOIN working wo 
        ON w.estimid = wo.estimid
        AND w.id != wo.id
        AND w.analyst IS NOT NULL
        AND wo.analyst IS NOT NULL
        AND wo.anndats_converted BETWEEN DATE_SUB(w.anndats_converted, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND w.anndats_converted
    GROUP BY w.id) temp ON temp.analyst = w.analyst;
```

And I saw all possible pairings for each person, like this:

```
| id | analyst | ireccd | id | analyst | min_ireccd |
+----+---------+--------+----+---------+------------+
| 1  |  DAVE   |    2   | 8  |  DAVE   |      null  |
| 1  |  DAVE   |    2   | 4  |  DAVE   |      1     |
| 1  |  DAVE   |    2   | 1  |  DAVE   |      1     |
| 1  |  DAVE   |    2   | 2  |  DAVE   |      1     |
| 1  |  DAVE   |    2   | 3  |  DAVE   |      1     |
```

Notice that compares the first `DAVE` with all other rows of `DAVE` in the table. **ALSO NOTE** I changed the above inner query to include an outer join so that all rows were considered. If there was nothing to calculate, the `min_ireccd` would be null.

The last thing I did was use that result set, and count the number of times the ireccd matched the min_ireccd. I grouped by id, so in the above sample set, it never matches, so the count would be 0. Here is the final query. It leaves null values (row 7) as null because that's what your expected results show:

```
SELECT w.*, SUM(w.ireccd = temp.min_ireccd) AS NO_TOP_RATING
FROM working w
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT w.id, w.analyst, MIN(wo.ireccd) AS min_ireccd
    FROM working w
    LEFT JOIN working wo 
        ON w.estimid = wo.estimid
        AND w.id != wo.id
        AND w.analyst IS NOT NULL
        AND wo.analyst IS NOT NULL
        AND wo.anndats_converted BETWEEN DATE_SUB(w.anndats_converted, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND w.anndats_converted
    GROUP BY w.id) temp ON temp.analyst = w.analyst
GROUP BY w.id;
```

These are the results I got:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @McAdam331 you for your answer. I will be sure to go over this thoroughly. I truly appreciate your time :)

Comment: @Kreeverp any progress?

Comment: I go a little stumped when I saw that your results table produced "1" for record #5 - instead of for record #6 - as it should in my given example.